# Error al conectar MySQL con Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, hibernate

Al creer Hibernate Reverse Engineering file (reveng.xml) no me deja ver las bases de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si tenga que ver el fallo con que en workbech me salga un `warning` Could not connect, server may not be running.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="MiConexion">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/alumno12</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">manager</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error me daba por que Workbench no me estaba funcionando la conexión, así que tuve que reinstalarlo y pude finalizar la conexion de MYSQL con Hibernate.